# IIS Load Balancing with IBM WebSphere Liberty Profile

Tags: iis, websphere, websphere-liberty

I am trying to setup IIS (version 8.x, windows 2008) in front of two IBM WAS(Liberty Profile Version 8.5.5) servers.

I have also deployed my Runtime on both the WAS Servers and individually they both are working totally fine.

When I am trying to configure both in IIS, I am getting following issue :
When I hit /, It opens the Console but after supplying username and password and hit enter, It again shows me the login page.

After going through the log trace, I think there is some issue with setting cookie JSESSIONID, But I couldn't find a way to resolve it.

My plugin-cfg.xml looks like following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Config ASDisableNagle="false" AcceptAllContent="false" AppServerPortPreference="HostHeader" ChunkedResponse="false" FIPSEnable="false" IISDisableNagle="false" IISPluginPriority="High" IgnoreDNSFailures="false" RefreshInterval="60" ResponseChunkSize="64" SSLConsolidate="false" TrustedProxyEnable="false" VHostMatchingCompat="false">
   <Log LogLevel="Trace" Name="C:\AppServer\Logs\http_plugin.log"/>
   <Property Name="ESIEnable" Value="true"/>
   <Property Name="ESIMaxCacheSize" Value="1024"/>
   <Property Name="ESIInvalidationMonitor" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="ESIEnableToPassCookies" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="PluginInstallRoot" Value="."/>
   <VirtualHostGroup Name="default_host">
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9443"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:443"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:80"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9080"/>
   </VirtualHostGroup>
   <ServerCluster CloneSeparatorChange="false" GetDWLMTable="false" IgnoreAffinityRequests="true" LoadBalance="Round Robin" Name="defaultServer_default_node_Cluster" PostBufferSize="0" PostSizeLimit="-1" RemoveSpecialHeaders="true" RetryInterval="60">
      <Server CloneID="server1111" ConnectTimeout="5" LoadBalanceWeight="2" ExtendedHandshake="false" MaxConnections="-1" Name="default_node_defaultServer0" ServerIOTimeout="900" WaitForContinue="false">
         <Transport Hostname="<IP1>" Port="9080" Protocol="http"/>
         <Transport Hostname="<IP1>" Port="9443" Protocol="https">
            <Property Name="keyring" Value="keyring.kdb"/>
            <Property Name="stashfile" Value="keyring.sth"/>
            <Property Name="certLabel" Value="LibertyCert"/>
         </Transport>
      </Server>
      <Server CloneID="server2222" ConnectTimeout="5" LoadBalanceWeight="2" ExtendedHandshake="false" MaxConnections="-1" Name="default_node_defaultServer1" ServerIOTimeout="900" WaitForContinue="false">
         <Transport Hostname="<IP2>" Port="9080" Protocol="http"/>
         <Transport Hostname="<IP2>" Port="9443" Protocol="https">
            <Property Name="keyring" Value="keyring.kdb"/>
            <Property Name="stashfile" Value="keyring.sth"/>
            <Property Name="certLabel" Value="LibertyCert"/>
         </Transport>
      </Server>
      <PrimaryServers>
         <Server Name="default_node_defaultServer0"/>
         <Server Name="default_node_defaultServer1"/>
      </PrimaryServers>
   </ServerCluster>
   <UriGroup Name="default_host_defaultServer_default_node_Cluster_URIs">
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/worklightconsole/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/wladmin/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/appcenterconsole/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/HelloWorld/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/applicationcenter/*"/>
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/IBMJMXConnectorREST/*"/>
   </UriGroup>
   <Route ServerCluster="defaultServer_default_node_Cluster" UriGroup="default_host_defaultServer_default_node_Cluster_URIs" VirtualHostGroup="default_host"/>
</Config>
```

Following is the trace log of IIS:

[Tue Sep 29 09:40:46 2015] 00000f10 00001430 - DEBUG: ws_common: websphereHandleSessionAffinity: Checking for session affinity

[Tue Sep 29 09:40:46 2015] 00000f10 00001430 - DEBUG: ws_common: websphereHandleSessionAffinity: Checking the SSL cookie affinity: SSLJSESSION

[Tue Sep 29 09:40:46 2015] 00000f10 00001430 - DEBUG: lib_htrequest: htrequestGetCookieValue: Looking for cookie: 'SSLJSESSION'

[Tue Sep 29 09:40:46 2015] 00000f10 00001430 - DEBUG: lib_htrequest: htrequestGetCookieValue: No cookie found for: 'SSLJSESSION'

[Tue Sep 29 09:40:46 2015] 00000f10 00001430 - DEBUG: ws_common: websphereHandleSessionAffinity: Checking the cookie affinity: JSESSIONID

[Tue Sep 29 09:40:46 2015] 00000f10 00001430 - DEBUG: lib_htrequest: htrequestGetCookieValue: Looking for cookie: 'JSESSIONID'

[Tue Sep 29 09:40:46 2015] 00000f10 00001430 - DEBUG: lib_htrequest: htrequestGetCookieValue: No cookie found for: 'JSESSIONID'

[Tue Sep 29 09:40:46 2015] 00000f10 00001430 - DEBUG: ws_common: websphereHandleSessionAffinity: Checking the url rewrite affinity: jsessionid

[Tue Sep 29 09:40:46 2015] 00000f10 00001430 - DEBUG: ws_common: websphereParseSessionID: Parsing session id from '/worklightconsole/login.html'

[Tue Sep 29 09:40:46 2015] 00000f10 00001430 - DEBUG: ws_common: websphereParseSessionID: No session found for jsessionid

[Tue Sep 29 09:40:46 2015] 00000f10 00001430 - DEBUG: ws_common: websphereHandleSessionAffinity: Bypassing check for partitionID cookie affinity.  No stored partition table.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't include the part of the trace that would have shown the request headers. 

Was there a Cookie request header? 
What was the name of the cookie that resembles the session ID and route?

Comment: Maybe you did not properly setup sticky sessions?

Comment: worklight console doesn't create any session, am I right?

Comment: In your browser, check if JSESSIONID cookie is created and if cloneID in the cookie matches cloneID in the plugin-cfg.xml. Maybe your browser is blocking cookies.  In `server.xml` you should have configured cloneID like this `<httpSession cloneId="server1111"/> and 2222 in second.

Comment: I have already configured cloneID in server.xml for both the servers. Still I am facing the same issue. When I login into worklight console it again shows me the worklight console login page. In the messages.log, I am getting this error : The security token cannot be validated.